# Are requirejs shim dependencies guaranteed to load before regular module dependencies?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Given a config like

```
require.config({ shim: { main: ['one'], one: ['two'] });
```

and a main module like

```
define('main', ['somethingThatUsesOneAndTwo'], function (s) {  });
```

are the global scripts `one` and `two` guaranteed to have executed by the time that `somethingThatUsesOneAndTwo` executes?

I'm aware that it's possible to create shim configuration entries that express the dependence of `somethingThatUsesOneAndTwo` on `one` and `two` but I haven't seen this fail even in a couple large and complex projects so I'm wondering if it's perhaps supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you have here this will work correctly, but I don't think it's best practice going forward.

This works because your shim has required that main depends upon `one` and `one` depends upon `two`.  When `main` is attempted to start `two` will run, then `one` will run, and finally `somethingThatUsesOneAndTwo` will run.

This is however not very straightforward at all.  For example why do you have a shim for `main` and use `define` in your main module?

If `somethingThatUsesOneAndTwo` really depends upon `one` and `two` then you should shim it to depend on those so that it will work correctly if it were imported in another module that didn't happen to have the dependencies set up like `main` does.

Comment: I agree that this isn't a best practice but the approach was used (not by me) to convert a large legacy project into something more manageable. In our case the main application file has shim dependencies on the global scripts that are always assumed to be loaded. The best thing to do would be to really express the dependencies of each module.